# How to insert multiple URLs with a title for each URL in an SharePoint List Column?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-list

I am trying to know if there is a way to insert multiple URLs and give a title to each URL in a column. For reference, please have a look at this below image.

[image]

In this list, we have Title, Name and ArtifactLink. The Name column has duplicate values, so may I know If there is a way like **Name -> Agile**, **ArtifactLink -> Planning Poker Guidance with it's URL and Project Startup with it's URL**.

Comment: If you are using column with "Hyperlink/Picture" data type, it is not possible to add multiple URLs in single field.

Comment: Ok. But I figured it by using Embed Code in that column and also use enhanced rich text(pictures, hyperlinks). It's showing results. But when I use REST API to retrieve artifactLink column data, it shows html data there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Hyperlink column type doesn't accept more than 1 link(cannot contains two or more links). You can use **Multiple lines of Text** column to achieve your needs.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a **Multiple lines of Text column** and check "**Use enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)**" option.

[image]

2.Edit item and click on the **Edit icon** next to the column.

[image]

3.On the Edit panel, click on "**Return to classic experience**" link

[image]

4.On the Classic Edit panel, click on **Edit Source**.

[image]

5.On th HTML Source panel, enter the code similar to the following:

```
<a href="https://www.bing.com/">Bing</a>
<br/><br/>​
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google​​</a>
```

[image]

6.Save

[image]